# How can I use rsync to duplicate a directory tree, creating hardlinks to files?

Tags: mac-osx, rsync, hardlink

From time to time, I have to perform several large migration changes on data files on my server, and I'm looking for a good way to do this. I was thinking about using rsync to duplicate my directory structure starting at the root data folder, creating hard links to all original the files (some of them are rather big), and I can overwrite in the destination tree only the files that need migrating. In the end, I can safely switch from the old files to the new files with two `mv` operations.

However, I can't seem to get rsync to do this. I tried

```
rsync -a --link-dest=$DATA $DATA $DATA/../upgrade_tmp
```

but instead of creating hard links to files, rsync copies them entirely. Is there a problem using the same source and link-dest directory?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`rsync` is a powerful tool, but it is, unfortunately, strangely picky about some of its pathnames.

If `$DATA` is an absolute path (i.e. it begins with a `/`), then the correct command-line to use is:

```
rsync -a --link-dest=$DATA $DATA/ $DATA/../upgrade_tmp
```

[Now, just a brief aside about `rsync`'s strangeness. Note the trailing `/` added to the source argument. This tells `rsync` to work with the *contents* of the source directory, rather than with the source directory itself. (I'm assuming that `$DATA` doesn't already contain a trailing `/`.) In this case, we want to work with the contents, so we add the trailing `/`.]

If, on the other hand, `$DATA` is a relative path (i.e. it does not begin with a `/`), then Sean R's comment about `--link-dest` is bang on: The link-dest path is interpreted relative to the *destination* path, so you would use the following:

```
rsync -a --link-dest=../`basename $DATA` $DATA/ $DATA/../upgrade_tmp
```

**EDIT**

One final note, it turns out that the second `rsync` command-line I gave should work regardless of whether `$DATA` is an absolute path, since `basename` doesn't care whether a path is absolute or relative.

Comment: Just a missing slash, who would have thought of that… Thanks for the nice explanation!

Comment: Thank you for this, I tried following several incremental backup instructions, like [this one](http://www.interlinked.org/tutorials/rsync_time_machine.html) and did not find any mention of this quirk. This was the only thing that actually ensured files were being hardlinked. Checking that ref count was > 1 and inode numbers were the same with `ls -ilah`

Comment: I used this in conjunction with the relpath() function described at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85068/57414 to backup a `$SOURCE` directory into a `$TARGET` dir like this: `SOURCE='abs_path_to_backup'; TARGET='.'; rsync -a --link-dest=$(relpath $TARGET $SOURCE) $SOURCE/ $TARGET/`

Answer (score 18):

What you want is "cp -al":

```
cp -al $DATA/ $DATA/../upgrade_tmp/
```

- -a recurses like `rsync -a`
- -l will hard link files instead of copying them.

Comment: `cp -al` is unfortunately not available on my system (Mac OS X 10.6). I'll use pax instead...

Answer (score 9):

Turns out it is more difficult to do this with `rsync` than with other tools. The correct answer for `rsync` is Steven Monai's, but the easiest way to do this is to use either `cp -al` or `pax -rwl` on systems where `-l` is not a valid option for `cp`:

```
pax -rwl $DATA $DATA/../upgrade_tmp
```

or

```
cp -al $DATA/ $DATA/../upgrade_tmp/
```

Answer (score 7):

The `--link-dest` option in `rsync` is relative to the **destination** directory, not the current directory.  So what you want is:

```
rsync -a --link-dest=../`basename $DATA` $DATA $DATA/../upgrade_tmp
```

Comment: Oops, I meant basename, originally I had dirname.

Comment: The man page says that `--link-dest` option, **if relative**, is relative to the target directory. In my case it's absolute. Even making it relative to the target directory does not make this work.

Answer (score 4):

It works for me:

```
$ rsync --hard-links --recursive --link-dest=/local user@host:/remote/ /local
```

I use rsync version 3.1.0.

From [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

> **--hard-links**
>
> Tells rsync to look for hard-linked files in the transfer, without
>   this option, hard-linked files in the transfer are treated as though
>   they were separate files.
>
> **--link-dest=DIR**
>
> Unchanged files are hard linked from DIR to the destination directory.
>   The files must be identical in all preserved attributes (e.g.
>   permissions, possibly ownership) in order for the files to be linked
>   together

Comment: Only code snippet is not enough, explain what it does and why.

Comment: **--hard-links**
Tells rsync to look for hard-linked files in the transfer, without this option, hard-linked files in the transfer are treated as though they were separate files.


**--link-dest=DIR**
Unchanged files are hard linked from DIR to the destination directory. The files must be identical in all preserved attributes (e.g. permissions, possibly ownership) in order for the files to be linked together.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you. Actually, I found your answer in the "low quality" queue. It means, there was a vote if your answer should be deleted or not. But not only the danger of the deletions is a reason to try to give a well-formatted, "human" answer, but it also helps a lot if you want to collect a upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Can try following link http://www.lessfs.com/wordpress/ it is work on [COW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628938/what-is-copy-on-write) (copy on write) that will save time and space

Comment: lessfs is very interesting, but is also very experimental. Not recommended for production use just yet.

Answer (score 2):

First create the directories only on the destination:

```
rsync -av --include '*/' --exclude '*' /source/ /destination/
```

Then hard link the files only:

```
cd /source
find . -type f -exec ln -v {} /destination/{} \;
```

Comment: Thanks — actually, I might as well use `pax` as shown in my comment above, which seems easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Option -H to preserve Hardlinks and read the manpage.

Comment: -H doesn't work. I have no hardlinks to preserve in my source tree, I just want a simple copy of my source tree where in the copy, all files are hardlinked to the original files. Sorry in my original question was unclear…

Comment: is "read the manpage" an answer? :-)